# Make own datatype without new modifier

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a Money datatype (like `int`, `string`) in C#. However I can't seem to work out how to use it without the `new` Modifier. The class cannot be static as it has to be assigned to. I figured there must be a way, here is the code I have for the class, I may be doing this completely wrong.

```
public class Money {
    private float _raw;

    public float Raw {
        get {  return _raw;  }
        set {  _raw = value;  }
    }

    public string Pound {
        get {  return "£" + string.Format("{0:0.00}", _raw);  }
    }
}
```

Then I have the class I am calling it in and would like to just use:

```
private Money _money;
```

Instead of:

```
private Money _money = new Money();
```

Sorry if this is a stupid question but I couldn't find anything online nor could I figure it out myself.

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `new`?

Comment: Don't use `float` for money. Use `decimal`.

Comment: You can't do it. That's not how the language works. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: You should make this type immutable, like int and string, then you can use struct as already indicated by an answer here. Since you've somewhat alluded to needing a mutable type, a struct is not an option, but that's what int, bool, datetime, is. Are you sure you need to be able to change it?

Comment: I think the answer you may be looking for would be to build your money type as a struct instead of a class. FWIW, you might want to consider basing it on decimal instead of float.

Comment: Thought it might be a good thing to learn. Didn't realise it wasn't possible. Thanks for not being harsh on me :).

Comment: @JoshHornsbyu Your question has thrown up all sorts of suggestions about class vs. struct, immutability, etc. You might find http://codereview.stackexchange.com useful if you want some more in-depth feedback on your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to new it up somewhere.  If you don't want to do it in the member declaration, then do it in the class constructor:

```
public MyClass()
{
     _money = new Money();
}
```

Comment: Better than that would be Factory Method, so you can do something like Money.Create(value)

Comment: You use a Factory method when you need to choose between different subtypes.  That's probably not the case here.

Comment: Not at all, Amy's answer shows a good way of creating the Money object from a method.

Comment: @bateloche: Meh.  You could do the same thing in a constructor.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution involves using a factory method of some kind.

```
public class Money {
    private float _raw;

    public float Raw {
        get {  return _raw;  }
        set {  _raw = value;  }
    }

    public string Pound {
        get {  return "£" + string.Format("{0:0.00}", _raw);  }
    }

    public static Money From(float val) 
    {
        Money x = new Money();
        x.Raw = val;
        return x;
    }
}
```

usage:

```
Money m = Money.From(9.95);
```

Comment: Your `From` method could be simplified even further using object initialisation i.e. `return new Money { Raw = val };`

Answer (score 2):

Using impilicit operator will allow you to set it like primitive data type.

http://haacked.com/archive/2012/09/30/primitive-obsession-custom-string-types-and-self-referencing-generic-constraints.aspx

```
public class Money

{
    private float _raw;

    public float Raw
    {
        get { return _raw; }
        set { _raw = value; }
    }

    public string Pound
    {
        get { return "£" + string.Format("{0:0.00}", _raw); }
    }


    public static implicit operator Money(float value)
    {
        return new Money(){Raw = value};
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this.

```
 Money m = 12;
 Console.Write(m.Raw);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use property Raw to assign value you can make a operator overload, something like that:

```
public static implicit operator Money(Double value)
{
    var money = new Money();

    money.Raw = value;

    return money;
}
```

And then in the calling code:

```
Money money = 10d;
```

But IMHO, i don't see any advantage in doing that, if you really need a muttable type, there should be no problem calling 'new' to instantiate it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a private constructor would prevent outsiders from "newing up" an instance... but then you also need to write a factory method or something to create it (in your class so that it has access to the private constructor). Otherwise your class is pretty useless!

That said, maybe if we knew why you didn't want to be able to "new up" an instance, we might be able to provide some tips.